# PHP - Remove everything after last occurance, with option to remove needle

Tags: php, string, function

I'm trying to create a function that will remove everything from the last occurrence of a word to the end of a string, with the option to remove that word also.

For example if I search for *cheese* in *The cheese is good and the cheese is yummy*, then *is yummy* would be removed.

But I also want an option to remove the word I searched for too. In that case I'd end up with *The cheese is good and the*.

I have a nice function that does this from the beginning of a string with the option. It looks like this...  but I can't seem to do the reverse.

```
function remove_before($needle, $haystack, $removeNeedle=false) {
    $pos = strpos($haystack, $needle);
    if ($pos!==false)
        return substr($haystack, $pos + (strlen($needle) * $removeNeedle) );
    else
        return $haystack;
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Comment: `preg_replace('~(.*\bcheese\b).*~s', '$1', $s)` or `preg_replace('~(.*)\bcheese\b.*~s', '$1', $s)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following `remove_after()` function:

```
function remove_after($needle, $haystack, $removeNeedle = false) {
    // getting the position of the last occurence of `$needle`
    $last_pos = strrpos($haystack, $needle);
    // if the `$needle` is found within `$haystack`
    if (($last_pos = strrpos($haystack, $needle)) !== false) {
        return substr($haystack, 0, $removeNeedle? $last_pos : $last_pos + strlen($needle));
    }
    return $haystack;
}

var_dump(remove_after("cheese", "The cheese is good and the cheese is yummy"));
var_dump(remove_after("cheese", "The cheese is good and the cheese is yummy", true));
```

The output:

```
string(33) "The cheese is good and the cheese"
string(27) "The cheese is good and the "
```

Comment: Thanks, help me understand.... what does the ? and : do in the substr?  Is this like an old-school if else statement?  Is there a way to make that more readable?    Thanks for your help.

Comment: I see now, it's a simpler way of writing...
    if ($removeNeedle==true) return substr($haystack,0,$last_pos);
    else return substr($haystack,0,$last_pos + strlen($needle));

Comment: @CheeseFlavored, yes, it's called ternary operator. http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

I think this solves the issue:

```
function remove_before($needle, $haystack, $removeNeedle=false) {
    $pos = strrpos($haystack, $needle);
    if ( !($pos === false) ) {
        if( !$removeNeedle )
            $pos += strlen($needle);
        $haystack = substr($haystack, 0, $pos);
    }
    return $haystack;
}

var_dump(remove_before("cheese", "The cheese is good and the cheese is yummy", true));
// Outputs: "The cheese is good and the "

var_dump(remove_before("cheese", "The cheese is good and the cheese is yummy"));
// Outputs: "The cheese is good and the cheese"
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how I originally wanted to solve the problem. Similar to my remove_before function....  Since keepNeedle is going to be a 1 or 0, you can simply multiply it in your substring so you don't need multiple If Else statements.

```
function remove_after($needle, $haystack, $keepNeedle=true) {
$last_pos = strrpos($haystack, $needle);
if ($last_pos!== false) return substr($haystack,0,$last_pos+(strlen($needle)*$keepNeedle));
return $haystack;}
```